# Skip properties when calling session.Merge in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want to support cascade update of "truncated graphs" in NHibernate.
Say I have a Student entity and a Class entity which has a Students collection. The Students collection is mapped with "cascade all". Now, suppose that in the client only the a class entity was changed, so I want the client to be able to send only the class entity without the contained students. My approach is to let the client send the class entity with the Students property nullified and let the DAL understand that the Students collection should be ignored.
Unfortunately, when NHibernate gets null property class.Students when given to session.Merge, it disconnects the child students from the parent class by setting their FKs to null and/or deleting them (depending on the specific cascade option).
I would expect NHibernate to behave like that only when getting an empty collection and not when the collection is nullified.
Is there a way to workaround this? E.g. by telling NHibernate somehow to skip the nullified properties during merge?

Comment: maybe initialize the nullified Properties with the original values `var class = Session.Get<Class>(class.Id); Session.Evict(class); classFromClient.Students = class.Students; Session.Merge(classFromClient);`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `inverse = "true"` for the Student collection in the Class entity, so that it will not clear the FK.

Comment: But then I'll have to manage back references in the Student entity which is not what I want